# Conditional HTML need suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, dynamic-html

What will be better of these 2 cases. Just making sure I am using best practice.

```
<% if(isEdit){ %>
<input type="text" id="tabtitle" name="title" value=<%=Content%>/>
<%}else{%>
<input type="text" id="title" name="title"/>
<%}%>
```

OR

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
<% if(isEdit){ %>
   $("#title").val("<%=Content%>");
<%}%>
});
```

Comment: I'd have tagged the question 'java jsp javascript jquery' personally.

Comment: Far better than *either* of those would be a solution not involving any "scriptlets" at all, and which instead used JSTL/EL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second uses JavaScript / JQuery to modify the element. Since adding client-side code has no advantage I would take the first approach which is server-side only. Although without seeing the bigger picture it's hard to endorse this approach particularly either.

Answer (score 1):

I would go by the first approach because the conditional is there anyway, and the javascript doesn't add anything to the functionality. It's just a forced approach.

Additionally if you use server side, your code is going to be correct the time it hits the browser, and there will be no lag for the javacsript function to be called. Sometimes there's a flash, or a wipe when you change dom through javascript... You will be better without it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll prefer the first approach as Javascript is usually disabled by some users for security reasons

Comment: Not worried about that actually cause I have java-scripts all over my website .I can't think of a website out there without javascript/jquery.

Comment: it's not black and white. There is a concept of unobstrusive Javascript which ensures that in case if your browser doesn't support Javascript, it fallbacks to plain old html. That's one of the beauties of web stack. HTML, CSS and Javascript are so detached from each other that if one fails, the rest can do their bit. So now when you are actually your content using Javascript, then you are not showing any information at all to users without Javascript. No graceful degradation. Read how Gawker.com messed up their web site design using the same strategy few weeks ago. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Pointy's suggestion and use the expression language (EL) in your JSP.  You could just put:

```
<input type="text" id="${titleid}" name="title" value="${Content}"/>
```

Set your titleid property to "title" or "tabtitle" and Content to "" or your content.  I haven't tested it but I believe that would accomplish the same thing.